# Img in flex container taking extra space?

Tags: html, css, image, flexbox

HTML: (there are 5 such `li`'s)

```
 <ul id='today-forecast'>
            <li class='today-item'>
                <div class='time'>Time</div>
                <img class='icon'></img>
                <div class='temp'>Temp</div>
            </li>
 </ul>
```

CSS:

```
#today-forecast {
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
#today-forecast .today-item {
  flex-grow: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: blue;
}

#today-forecast .today-item img{
  display: block; background-color: blue; }
```

JS

```
export function iconSetter(img, name) {
  //img <-img tag selected from document, name <- name of icon
  name = '01n' //from: https://openweathermap.org/weather- 
               //conditions
  img.src = `http://openweathermap.org/img/wn/${name}@2x.png`; 
}
```

Preview with flexbox gridlines:

[image]

The background color shows that the issue probably isn't with the image but the container.
There's no flex-grow: 1 on the children of `.today-item`. I also tried justify-content: flex-start, and it didn't work. Setting the height doesn't resolve the issue here, but it did for another part of my page.

Comment: Add code snippet. For image use some online image address.

Comment: The code in your question doesn't reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't your `<img>` tag wrong.`<img>` tag is void element, so it should not have closing tag.
To remove the extra space around the icon we can just crop it.

```css
#today-forecast {
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

#today-forecast .today-item {
  flex-grow: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: blue;
}

#today-forecast .today-item span {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#today-forecast .today-item img {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: -25px 0 0 -25px;
}
```

```html
 <ul id='today-forecast'>
   <li class='today-item'>
     <div class='time'>Time</div>
     <span><img class="icon" src="http://openweathermap.org/img/wn/01n@2x.png"></span>
     <div class='temp'>Temp</div>
   </li>
 </ul>
```

Comment: Fixed that, no change.

Comment: @GoldCredential Run this code snippet. Do you need something like this. change the icon size if needed.

Comment: I want the eliminate the unnecessary space surrounding the image in the picture in my question.

Comment: @GoldCredential Try running the code snippet now, does it solve your problem now?

Comment: It doesn't go well with my layout

Comment: I placed a span as you did and then this CSS code worked for me: https://pastebin.com/xa8CAf5d